# Wildfly access file in standalone/lib

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-8

i´m currently writing a web-application, which shall fetch some websites, crawl them for information and send these informations to my email.

Now i´m thinking about, how to make the application configurable. I don´t want to set my email-adress in the code.

My thought is, to store a config.xml file in the wildfly standalone/lib folder and then accessing this easily in the code? Would this be possible, or have you nicer solutions?

Comment: Maybe your question is duplicated. Look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953261/wildfly-reading-properties-from-configuration-directory)

Comment: What you're asking is possible, but there are A LOT of ways to do it.  Take a look at how to read XML, or other types of configuration files in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to your standalone.xml under `<system-properties>`

`<property name="my.email.address" value="you@something.com"/>`

and in your code get it with:

```
String emailAddress = System.getProperty("my.email.address");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer- this works very well :)
But if i want to read a configuration XML-file, which i´ll store on the wildfly, how can i access this? If i would have more than just one parameter, this would be better.

Comment: Im not sure I follow what you asking but you can add as many properties as you wish, is not limited to just 1 property, hope that answers you.