# How to use @Resource (in javax.annotation) or @InjectableResource (in DeltaSpike) to inject login-config.xml in JBoss 4.2.x?

Tags: java, jboss, deltaspike

As the title says, how do I load the [login-config.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/installguide/r1/en/html/config-files.html) file under `jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\conf\` using [DeltaSpike](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/core.html#InjectingResources)?

The following gives a `NullPointerException` when trying to do `properties.toString()` (JBoss starts fine):

```
@InjectableResource(location="/login-config.xml")
private Properties properties;
```

---

I've also tried [`javax.annotation.Resource`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/annotationapi/javax/annotation/Resource.html), which gives a `NullPointerException` with `JndiUtil.lookup()`, when JBoss starts up:

```
@Resource(mappedName="login-config.xml")
private Properties properties;
```

Exception:

```
2021-10-14 14:29:52,420 [http-127.0.0.1-8443-5] ERROR [STDERR] 0 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.ejb3.JndiUtil.lookup(JndiUtil.java:49)
    at org.jboss.injection.JndiPropertyInjector.lookup(JndiPropertyInjector.java:87)
    at org.jboss.injection.JndiPropertyInjector.inject(JndiPropertyInjector.java:112)
    at org.jboss.injection.JndiPropertyInjector.inject(JndiPropertyInjector.java:107)
    at org.jboss.injection.JndiPropertyInjector.inject(JndiPropertyInjector.java:65)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27953571/3380951

Comment: unit test from deltaspike: [here](https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/tree/master/deltaspike/core/impl/src/test/java/org/apache/deltaspike/test/core/impl/resourceloader)

Comment: unit test from deltaspike using [WebResourceProvider](https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/master/deltaspike/modules/servlet/impl/src/test/java/org/apache/deltaspike/test/servlet/impl/resourceloader/WebResourceProviderTest.java)